# Setting default ubuntu desktop backgrounds

Tags: 12.04, playonlinux, desktop-background

How to change the default desktop background?
A list of background pictures are available in the preference window, but I want to make my own picture as a default wallpaper. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I want to  make my own  default wallpapers, which means not selecting the file and setting it as wallpaper but defining user desired images as default wallpaper.
Step 1:In the terminal type the following
 sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/precise-wallpapers.xml 

/*This opens the a file where the location of the images is coded. */
 then in the page edit the following

Illustration with example:

Morning Dew 
    
/usr/share/backgrounds/Morning_Dew_by_Lars_Clausen.jpg 
    zoom 
    
#000000 
    
#000000 
    
solid

rename the following thing

1) morning dew  :- example 
2) /usr/share/backgrounds/Morning_Dew_by_Lars_Clausen.jpg :- /usr/share/backgrounds/example.jpg

Then the file looks something like this

example
 
    /usr/share/backgrounds/example.jpg 
    
zoom 
    
#000000 
    
#000000 
    
solid

End of step 1

Step 2: in the terminal 
 sudo ls /usr/share/backgrounds/
    /*then a list of images is displayed*/
and copy a image named example.jpg 
 paste in this folder /*do it any way you know*/
 End of step 2

Now it is almost done check your background 
i.e right click + personalize
 then there appears your example.jpg as a default ubuntu wallpaper.
Select your own wallpaper which is now a default wallpaper.